# Latex is stuck on previous page

Tags: spacing

PDFLatex uses an unused space in the previous page. I want to write where I am left, onto the last page but latex still does not skip this empty space left on the previous page.

`\end{figure} 1234567 \end{document}`[image: empty space is bordered by red but texmaker does not give error.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  I'm having trouble understanding your question.  "uses an unused" doesn't make sense.  Now does "latex still does not skip the empty space".  Are you saying that you want the text `1234567` to come after the figure, but the text is coming before and the figure is getting moved to the next page?  In that case:

Comment: you have only shown a fragment of code and a fragment of output it is really hard to guess what you have done or what the problem is.